# How to Shutdown Xamarin forms App to BackButton?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm making a Xamarin Forms App, and I want to put the ability to go back to the app screen via a hardware Back Button and exit the app when pressed on the first page.

I tried several codes to pass the Page name to OnBackPressed in MainActivity and to terminate the app when the corresponding parameter has the MainPage name.

1. When a Back Button Event occurs in the page the user is currently viewing, the name of the page is delivered.

   (var Pages = Xamarin.Forms.Page.Page) -> Does not working
2. Apply Environment.Exit(1) in OnBackPressed() function in Page.xaml.cs -> Does not work

Other than that, I tried many ways, but it didn't work.

Is there a way to kill the app with a hardware Back Button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can provide an incomplete solution.

At first, the app can be killed with one line code in the android:

```
 Android.OS.Process.KillProcess(Android.OS.Process.MyPid());
```

So you can try to override the OnBackPressed() method in the MainActivity and do a judgement. Such as:

```
 public override void OnBackPressed()
    {
        base.OnBackPressed();
        If() // if the page is the first page. or if a flag is true
          Android.OS.Process.KillProcess(Android.OS.Process.MyPid());
    }
```

You can also do this in the forms:

```
 protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        if()//Judge whether the current page is the first page
        {
           System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill(); 
        }
        return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
    }
```

Comment: In the first code snippet, perhaps switch the order of statements, so that `base.OnBackPressed();` doesn't execute until *after* deciding whether to kill app.

Comment: Thanks for providing the solution. Let's test it by applying that method.
What I understood
I understood that the app can be terminated by passing the corresponding flag as True in the page that you want to close through the hardware back button, and examining the parameter with an If statement.

Comment: It is not a parameter method, but I confirmed again that the current page should be checked in MainActivity. Thank you.

Comment: You can try to override the OnBackButtonPressed() method in the form's page. Just use the code I provided.  It doesn't have to be a parameter method.@user18501010