# How to put an exit icon that close the app in the main screen?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, icons

The title is the question right here, but to be more specific, i'll show the example. [Exit icon as i want to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjsTx.png)

Comment: Sorry, question is vague, or has more than one part to solving it. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Is your primary question "How do I programmatically close an app"?  If so, then google that. Not surprisingly, you aren't the first person to wonder how to do that!

Comment: You don't.  iOS expressly prohibits this.  Android discourages it, although you can use the button to navigate to the home screen, but it does not close the app.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following lines of code in your icon's OnClickListener,

```
MainActivity.this.finish();
System.exit(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to `terminate` an application via a click event in Xamarin Forms.

For more details, you can refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72010683/how-to-shutdown-xamarin-forms-app-to-backbutton).

```
  private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
        }
```